# expose lastpassword reset date for external accounts azure-ad-b2c

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any Api to get the  users
 last changed password date for external accounts 
 who are signed up using the AD-B2C policies. we have tried using the graph Api but we dont have such property in the users Json.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, this **user** property isn't available.